# Programming macro to color rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to program a macro that colors the rows where it finds a 0 
value in the current column. I am unsure how to fix it though because 
it only does the first Range selection to the right ignoring the rest.

How can I tell the command to select all cells to the right of the current 
one up to Column T?

```
  Sub FindAndColor()
  '
  ' FindAndColor Macro
  '
  ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D
  '
      Cells.Find(What:="0", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
          xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
          False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
      Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
      Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
      Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
      Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
      Selection.Style = "Bad"
  End Sub
```

Also, I would like it to put me in the cell below the current one? What needs
to go in place of "A1" so that it is the current cell and not A1.

```
  Range("A1").Offset(0,1)
```

Any help appreciated,

Ted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to loop through all the rows of the sheet and change the formatting of any row where the currently selected column is 0?  If so, the below will work without using .Select (.Select is evil).

```
Sub FindAndColor2()
    'This code will find each row with 0 in the currently selected column
    '   and color the row from column 1 to 20 (A to T) red and set the
    '   font to bold.
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long


'Get the column of the current selection
col = Selection.Column
'Loop through every row in the active worksheet
For row = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'If the cell's value is 0.
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Text = 0 Then
        'Put your formatting inside this with.  Note that the 20 in .cells(row, 20)
        '   is column T.
        With ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 20))
            .Interior.Color = vbRed
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Style = "Bad"
            'Other formatting here
        End With
    End If
Next row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked something about VBA, but in a case like this, you might want to consider using [conditional formating](http://www.contextures.com/xlcondFormat01.html). If it's not applicable, you can go with

```
Range([Fill Me]).Interior.Color = vbRed
```

or

```
Cells([Fill Me]).Interior.Color = vbRed
```